# How to create a rating bar(Or linear gauge) using material UI (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React, I want to create a rating bar like this:
[image]

I want to use material UI, but I didn't find a component like this.
I found a rating UI component: https://material-ui.com/components/rating/. but I need the UI to be like a linear gauge and change color with a different number (`1/5, 2/5,3/5,4/5,5/5)`.

Actually, I already used the rating component:

```
                <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.overAllScoreValueContainer}>
                    <Box component="fieldset" marginLeft={0} marginTop={0.25} padding={0} borderColor="transparent">
                        <Rating
                            name="overall-score"
                            value={this.state.overAllRating}
                            readOnly
                            size={"large"}
                            classes={{
                                iconFilled: this.props.classes.iconFilled,
                                iconHover: this.props.classes.iconHover
                            }}
                        />
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
```

but the UI is not correct.

anyone can help?

Thank you for pointing out using the progress bar in material UI.
I can make the shape like what shown in the picture, but how to change color according to the value??
please check this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-water-cx6dd?file=/demo.js

Comment: Do you try `Progress` in MUI: https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#customized-progress

Answer (score 1):

You can use material ui progress... see the document.
https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#progress

You can also customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for posting your sandbox. I was able to provide the color dynamically with your help. If you're still stuck here then just pass the color as a prop and `!important` to your style. Thank you soo much.

Here's the updated sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-bird-dh50kl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A high level solution without using any third party css libraries.

1). Declare multiple div's. parent will be the background color of your bar and child will be the fillable element. In child element 3/5*100, 3 refers to the rating and 5 refers to the maximum rating level. with the help of multiplying with 100 we can get the percentage level.**So based on the percentage you can fill the background width with orange color**. **Here 3/5 * 100 = 60. so it will fill upto 60%**

HTML :

```
<div className="rectangle-box">
                    <div className="fillable-box" style{{width:`${(3/5)*100}%`,height: "100%"}} />
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
.rectangle-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.fillable-box {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Final output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#progress component and modify the styles using the styled library integrartion provided by MUI

```
const colorMapping = {
  20: "red",
  40: "orange",
  60: "yellow",
};

 

const BorderLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(({ theme, ...props }) => ({
  margin: 10,
  height: 15,
  backgroundColor: "#ddd",

  ["& .MuiLinearProgress-bar"]: {
    backgroundColor: colorMapping[props.value],
    borderRight: "3px solid  #fff",
  },
}));

<BorderLinearProgress variant="determinate" value={40} />
```

Here is the code sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-field-kdnhcz

Check the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpcZ0.png)